# Retrieve image from mysql database in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to retrieve image using the image path (which saved in the database) in the array index.

like-

```
< img src= "< ? php echo base_url().$info['/assets/img/women_collection/2/main_image_gallery.jpg'];? >" / >
```

But it does not woring!.

plz help!
.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Please, pass your path as a parameter to `base_url()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $info is your database results?

Your array key should be the database table row.

```
$info['image']
```

Comment: it's real foolishness !!! :P
i was using the image path instead of using the database row!!
the index should be the row of the database.

like this-
 
< img src= " < ? php echo base_url().$info['gallery_image']; ? > " / >

Comment: You're welcome. You should follow Brett's advice too, and pass this as a parameter to the base_url function.